# Add GridView as the footer of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I am working in an android application am I am having a GridView with 8 images in it. I want to add the GridView as the footer of the ListView. After adding, the added footer ie the GridView
shows only the first two images in the ListView and the rest of the images are not shown in the ListView. I think only the first row of the GridView is shown.

Please look into my xml and code

```
    <GridView
            android:layout_below="@+id/homescreen_top_RelativeLayout"
            android:id="@+id/homescreen_gridview"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="@dimen/gridViewcolumnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:layout_above="@+id/homescreen_logout"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />


public class ImageAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdaptor(Context context) {

        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {



            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subrow_gridview, null);

            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_TextView);

            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            gridView.setTag(position);
            textView.setText(mImagesValues[position]);

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mImages = { R.drawable.care, R.drawable.bus,
            R.drawable.monthly_summary,R.drawable.care,R.drawable.care,R.drawable.care,R.drawable.care,R.drawable.care };

    // Keep all Images in array
    public String[] mImagesValues = { "Service " + "\n" + "Entry",
            "Bus" + "\n" + "Attendance", "Monthly" + "\n" + "Summary","Monthly" + "\n" + "Summary","Monthly" + "\n" + "Summary","Monthly" + "\n" + "Summary","Monthly" + "\n" + "Summary" };
}
```

Comment: Why do you do gridView = new View(mContext); ?

Comment: @2Dee. Sorry. that was a mistake..I have updated my code.

Comment: @Vojtaaa9. No.. My requirement is to show eight images in the gridview and add that gridview as the footer of the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this is an adapter for gridview, modify your getView() as follows.

add a ViewHolder class as follows.

```
static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.subrow_gridview, null);

        // set image based on selected text
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_TextView);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
    viewHolder.textView.setText(mImagesValues[position]);
    return convertView;;
}
```

This is completely untested code.